# Calendar selected index change doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, selectedindexchanged

I have a calendar which disappears on selecting a date ..but if I select the same date again, the the calendar selected index change doesn't fire..

How do I handle this for same date selection?

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   dt = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

   string date;
   date = dt.Year.ToString() + "/" + dt.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt.Day.ToString();
   txtpickupdate.Text = date;
   Calendar1.Visible = false;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Why would you have to for the same date?

Comment: Because selection is not changed?

Comment: SelectionChanged Event is fired only when change in date. you can raise the event for Calendar_Load.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Functionality with same date. You have to write the Calendar_Load event.

Please see the sample

```
 protected void Calendar1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
            {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt=Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            string date;
            date = dt.Year.ToString() + "/" + dt.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt.Day.ToString();
            txtpickupdate.Text = date;
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
           }
    }
```